# Angular 5 regex match any Unicode alphabet letter

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, unicode, angularjs-directive

How can I match any Unicode letter (no symbol, number or any other kind of character), i.e. letter from alphabet of any language, in the Angular `pattern` directive? Previously I've used AngularJS and I've just installed *XRegExp* plugin for it, but since Angular 5 is using *TypeScript*, I was trying to find a way to do this without using the mentioned plugin. But I can't seem to find any other way...

EDIT: I'm looking for a straightforward way, without using plugins and without insanely long list of unicode charater ranges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes)

Comment: You can use a javascript library in a typescript project as well. You will just lack of type support

Comment: @revo It does not provide a nice way of doing this. I'm looking for a nicer way, than just specifying an insanely long range of unicode characters...

Comment: There is no nicer way to do it until major browsers implement new ECMA features and support of unicode properties.